# How to return a promise for a simple redux action creator?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux

I have a function `add` where no promises is returned to the caller.

For example:

```
let add = (foo) => {this.props.save(foo)};
```

And in another function of my application I would like to do:

```
...
return  add()
        .then( ... do something else here ... );
```

I just want to wait till `add()` is done and then do something else. I understand async `save` does not return a promise. Its a simple redux action.

```
 export const save = (something) => (dispatch) => {

  ApiUtil.patch(`google.com`, { data: { 
 something  } }).
   then(() => {
  dispatch({ type: Constants.SET_FALSE });
  },
() => {
  dispatch({ type: Constants.SET_SAVE_FAILED,
    payload: { saveFailed: true } });
});
};
```

I have pasted it here to show action

Comment: You didn't include the definition of save()...

Comment: meant to say add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you are using redux-thunk for async actions, since your `add` action creator is in fact returning a function that accepts `dispatch` rather than a simple action object.

If you are using redux-thunk, then whatever you return from your thunk will be propagated back out. So if you modify your code such that:

```
let add = (foo) => this.props.save(foo); // Now returns result of save
```

Then update your thunk to:

```
export const add = (something) => (dispatch) =>
    ApiUtil.patch(`google.com`, { data: { something } })
        .then(() => { dispatch({ type: Constants.SET_FALSE }); },
            () => { dispatch({ type: Constants.SET_SAVE_FAILED, payload: { saveFailed: true }});}
        );
```

(Where you'll notice I removed the outside-most curlies), then the promise from ApiUtil should bubble all the way back up and you should be able to .then on it.

Comment: Assuming `ApiUtil.patch()` returns a promise, you can chain it from the callee, at the `this.props.save()` call, but it does not necessarily mean the promise returned was resolved or got rejected the way you have in this answer. This is actually a big issue with redux-thunk (see  https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1676 ).

Answer (score 1):

First you have to understand what `this.props.save()` returns. If it returns a promise, then you need only return that from add:

```
const add = (foo) => { return this.props.save(foo); }
```

So the problem is just what the definition of save is.